# Can we use props to pass variable in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

Slall question:

I have a 2 parent components nesting the same child component inside of them.
I use props so the parents can tell the child what title to show.

this child component is a photo gallery. It makes a query to the database, download photos and show them up. classic.

I need the parents to tell the child where to get the photos from:
Get the photos from All users, for the home page
or
get only the photos from a specific user for a user's page.

I'm wondering if I can pass this information through a prop.
Is that possible? Can we use the info from a prop as a varialble inside of the setup() function?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why does one not simply show us the code? *boromir meme*

Comment: Show us some code please. [ask]

Comment: My code doesn't make any sense. I don't even know if it is possible. I just want to know if it is possible for a child component tu use a prop as a value in function.

Comment: Basicly, I just want to know if there is a way to console.log a prop in the child component. I'm working with the composition api and the setup() function.

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#props

Comment: Yes this is exactly what props are for. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html https://vueschool.io/lessons/reusable-components-with-props?friend=vuejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing objects from one component to a child component is the purpose of props.

You can pass many items through props. VueJS has the following types built-in:

- String
- Number
- Boolean
- Array
- Object
- Function
- Promise

In the [V3 VueJS guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#arguments) it gives the following example of a prop being passed into a component and then being logged to the console inside the `setup()` method.

```
export default {
  props: {
    title: String
  },
  setup(props) {
    console.log(props.title)
  }
}
```

However, when using props, you should always mark whether the is `required`, what its `type` is and what the `default` is if it is not required.

For example:

```
export default {
  props: {
    title: String, // This is the type
    required: false, // If the prop is required
    default: () => 'defaultText' // Default needed if required false
  },
  setup(props) {
    console.log(props.title)
  }
}
```

It's important to note that when using default, the value must be returned from a function. You cannot pass a default value directly.

Comment: !! setup(props) !! I think THIS is the only thing I was missing... I can't believe it was so simple. Thank you so much for your message!!! I wish I had asked the question straight away instead of searching on my own. I don't think I have seen this anywhere though. And I searched all day!! thanks again!!

Comment: No worries, @Posoroko! I'm glad this answer helped you. You can see the exact example I used and more examples on the page I linked in my answer. Please my answer as correct and upvote it if possible so it can have better visibility for any future visitors. Happy learning! :)